# Como poner otro valor en el inicio de mi select en mi formulario en django

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo un formulario con un select, que tiene los valores de un choice, cuando carga la página tiene puesto el primer valor del choice por defecto, como podria cambiarlo?

```html
class ListadoAlumno(forms.Form):
    Actividades = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Actividad.objects.all(), label='', widget=Select(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control select2',
        'style': 'width: 100%'
    }))
    Meses = CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=Meses,
                                                  attrs={
                                                      'class': 'form-control select2',
                                                      'style': 'width: 100%',
                                                      'autocomplete': 'off',
                                                      # 'multiple': 'multiple',
                                                      'placeholder': 'Seleccionar',
                                                  }))
```

Este sería el código, y el select es Meses, en el template está tal que así.

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
                        <label>Mes:</label>
                        {{ form.Meses }}

                    </div>
```

Como podría hacerlo para que el primer valor en vez de ser Enero, fuera por ejemplo
------------ o Seleccionar.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes colocar el parámetro initial para especificar un valor inicial

```
Actividades = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Actividad.objects.all(), initial=1)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, no es el select de actividades el que intento modificar, es el de meses, y es un choise, no quiero que cuando cargue salga por defecto el primer mes, sino en blanco, lo he conseguido hacer con Javascript, pero en django no sabría como hacerlos. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

prueba con:

`empty_label=("--Seleccione una fecha--")`

en las propiedades del ModelChoiceField antes del queryset